# Why Polhode is a circle in a symmetric body

Tags: classical-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics

[image]

Goldstein

> In the special case of a symmetrical body, the inertia ellipsoid is an ellipsoid of revolution, so that the polhode on the ellipsoid is clearly a circle about the symmetry axis. The herpolhode on the invariable plane is likewise a circle.

Why should the polhode and herpolhode be only circles for axisymmetric body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the body frame, the polhode is the intersection of Poinsot's ellipsoid (the surface $\pmb{\omega} \cdot \mathbf{I} \cdot \pmb{\omega} = \text{const.}$) with the surface $\mathbf{L} \cdot \mathbf{L} = \text{const.}$  For a symmetric body (with, say, $\lambda_2 = \lambda_3$) these equations become
$$
\lambda_1 \omega_1^2 + \lambda_3 (\omega_2^2 + \omega_3^2) = \text{const.}
$$
and
$$
\lambda_1^2 \omega_1^2 + \lambda_3^2 (\omega_2^2 + \omega_3^2) = \text{const.}
$$
We can see from these equations that both surfaces are symmetric under rotations about the $\mathbf{\hat{e}}_1$ axis, which implies that their intersection will also be symmetric under this rotation.  Thus, the polhode must be a circle.

It is also possible to show that the magnitude of $\pmb{\omega}$ is constant for a symmetric body.  The simplest argument (that I'm aware of) involves writing out Euler's equations in terms of $\omega_1, \omega_2$, and $\omega_3$. You can then show from these equations that $\omega_1$ is constant and that $\omega_2^2 + \omega_3^2 = \text{const.}$;  neither of these two quantities are constant for an asymmetric body.  This then means that $\pmb{\omega}^2$ is also constant.  So $\pmb{\omega}$ must always lie on the intersection between the invariable frame and a sphere, which means that the herpolhode is a circle on the invariable plane.

Comment: Thank you. In the body frame the invariable plane moves around the ellipsoid?

Comment: Also the way the author has written " In the special case of a symmetrical body, the inertia ellipsoid is an ellipsoid of revolution, so that the polhode on the ellipsoid is clearly a circle ..."it seems like its something oblivious geometrically but I'm not sure, can you see anything that makes it obvious to call it " clearly it is a circle"?

Comment: @Kashmiri:  The "clearly" argument, if spelled out, would basically be what I've written above.  If you define $\pmb{\omega}_\perp$ to be the projection of $\pmb{\omega}$ perpendicular to $\hat{e}_1$, then we have $\omega_2^2 + \omega_3^2 = \omega_\perp^2$, and the quantities above only depend on the magnitude of $\pmb{\omega}_\perp$ and not the direction it points.

Comment: @Kashmiri:  And yes, in the body frame, the $\hat{e}_1$ vector is fixed and the vectors $\pmb{\omega}$ and $\mathbf{L}$ move around.  In particular, since the invariable plane is the plane perpendicular to $\mathbf{L}$, it will move around in the body frame.  (Which means, I suppose, that it's not "invariable" in the body frame.)

Comment: @Kashmiri:  Updated to include argument about how the herpolhode is a circle.

Comment: Great! Thank you!